# Accidentally denied Facebook access to my Instagram page

Tags: facebook, instagram

While trying to set up my Instagram business page I accidentally denied Facebook permission. How do I go back and reset this so I can allow?

Answer (score 1):

After logging in your account, go to https://www.instagram.com/accounts/manage_access. You can change your account permissions from that page.